# InstallShield and Click-Once Setup

Tags: web, clickonce

How would I be able get ClickOnce to include and run an install or have it install with InstallShield and ClickOnce to install it as a prerequisite

Comment: You have some InstallShield package & ClickOnce application. So now you need to include ClickOnce application inside InstallShield package and somehow to deploy ClickOnce application for while installation is going right ?

Comment: Include the installshield package in the Clickonce application and send the return values from the installshield package to the web server